# Issue in headless testing

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, headless-browser

I have written a code in java using selenium web driver. I need to run that jar on the Google Computer Engine. I want headless testing so I have written below code for headless Firefox browser. Below is the link from where I got this idea.

http://www.seleniumtests.com/2012/04/headless-tests-with-firefox-webdriver.html

But still when I executed in GCE the browser is opening. Can someone please help?

```
String Xport = System.getProperty("lmportal.xvfb.id", ":1");
final File firefoxPath = new File(System.getProperty("lmportal.deploy.firefox.path", "/usr/bin/firefox"));
FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary(firefoxPath);
firefoxBinary.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY", Xport);

driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxBinary, null);
```

Comment: So , What issue you facing?

Comment: I was able to see the firefox browser. But i need headless firefox.

Comment: Refer this example : http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/headless-browser-testing-selenium-webdriver/

Comment: I just navigated through the link added in the Question. I see Xvfb Firefox need to be installed. Did you install Xvfb Firefox ?

Comment: Yes first i installed XVfb and firefox i already had. After that i started as per the instruction on the link